# Spark-submit on GCP dataproc shows java.io. FileNotFoundException error

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

All the cases are performed in GCP data proc cluster with a master and 4 executors.

**Case 1:** When I execute a runnable JAR file with the **spark-submit** in Local mode with **spark-config** as

`SparkConf config = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("ANNCLUSTERED");`

`spark-submit /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/RunSCL.jar /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/California_Nodes.txt /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/California_Edges.txt /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/California_part_4.txt 4 10000 10000 1`  
and run it on local mode, it runs without any issues.

**Case 2:** Setting the spark configuration on the source as:

```
        SparkConf config = new SparkConf().setAppName("ANNCLUSTERD").set("spark.locality.wait", "0")
                .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster").set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "6g")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "6g").setMaster("spark://34.80.87.222:7077").set("spark.cores.max", "8")
                .set("spark.blockManager.port", "10025").set("spark.driver.blockManager.port", "10026")
                .set("spark.driver.port", "10027").set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
                .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false");
```

and run the same **spark-submit** command I am getting this error:

```
22/11/15 08:45:37 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
22/11/15 08:45:37 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
22/11/15 08:45:37 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@40147317{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:0}
22/11/15 08:45:37 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
22/11/15 08:45:38 ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:517)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:296)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:855)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:948)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:517)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:296)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:855)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:948)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

**Case 3:** When I try to run the same JAR file in YARN cluster mode with 4 executors changing the config file to:

`SparkConf config=new SparkConf().setAppName("ANN-SCL");`

and the submit command I get this following error:

```
spark-submit --class main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 4 /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/RunSCL.jar /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/California_Nodes.txt /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/California_Edges.txt /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/California_part_4.txt 4 10000 10000 1
```

I get the following error, while the job gets accepted it never passes to the running stage.

```
Application application_1668488196607_0004 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1668488196607_0004_000002 exited with exitCode: 13
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2022-11-15 08:16:01.044]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1668488196607_0004_02_000001
Exit code: 13
[2022-11-15 08:16:01.086]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 13. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at framework.UtilsManagement.readEdgeTxtFileReturnGraph(UtilsManagement.java:382)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/California_Edges.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at edu.ufl.cise.bsmock.graph.YenGraph.readFromFile(YenGraph.java:171)
at edu.ufl.cise.bsmock.graph.YenGraph.<init>(YenGraph.java:21)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/California_Nodes.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at framework.UtilsManagement.readTxtNodeFile(UtilsManagement.java:210)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
22/11/15 08:16:00 ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:220)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:470)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:305)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.$anonfun$run$1(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:781)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1938)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:780)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:805)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
[2022-11-15 08:16:01.087]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 13. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at framework.UtilsManagement.readEdgeTxtFileReturnGraph(UtilsManagement.java:382)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/California_Edges.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at edu.ufl.cise.bsmock.graph.YenGraph.readFromFile(YenGraph.java:171)
at edu.ufl.cise.bsmock.graph.YenGraph.<init>(YenGraph.java:21)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/California_Nodes.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at framework.UtilsManagement.readTxtNodeFile(UtilsManagement.java:210)
at main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.main(GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:686)
22/11/15 08:16:00 ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:220)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:470)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:305)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.$anonfun$run$1(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:781)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1938)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:780)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:805)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://spark-cluster-m:8188/applicationhistory/app/application_1668488196607_0004 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

I am using the absolute file path to pass the file as an argument and but still running on the error. I am worried that my configurations are not correct

Answer (score 1):

Your file needs to exist on every executor, in the same location. Local mode obviously is only running on one machine... You can see in the Spark UI which node the code runs on, then you see `FileNotFoundException` in the logs, so then you can debug on your own by SSH to that machine and look around the file path to see if the exception is true...

You should upload the file to HDFS, not use local Unix file paths, or have Spark do it with the `--files` argument to spark-submit

Comment: ```spark-submit --class main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 4 /home/aavashbhandari/dataset/RunSCL.jar hdfs:///wsu/dataset/California_Nodes.txt hdfs:///wsu/dataset/California_Edges.txt hdfs:///wsu/dataset/California_part_4.txt 4 10000 10000 1
```

Comment: I have moved the files in the HDFS, but  I am still getting the same file not found an error! Is this the correct format to pass the HDFS path during the spark-submit?

Comment: ```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class main.GraphNetworkSCLAlgorithm --master yarn hdfs://spark-cluster-m:8020/wsu/dataset/RunSCL.jar hdfs://spark-cluster-m:8020/wsu/dataset/California_Nodes.txt hdfs://spark-cluster-m:8020/wsu/dataset/California_Edges.txt hdfs://spark-cluster-m:8020/wsu/dataset/California_part_4.txt 4 10000 10000 1
```

Comment: There is no "correct format" here because all arguments after your class name are passed as `String[] args` to your app, and therefore require you to show your code for how you actually use those values. As mentioned, you should ideally use `--files`, which will automatically upload the files to the YARN executor classpath Refer [Important notes section](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#important-notes)

Comment: ```String nodeDatasetFile = args[0];
  String edgeDataSetFile = args[1];
  String metisPartitionOutputFile = args[2];
  String partitionValue = args[3];
  String queryObjectSize = args[4];
  String dataObjectSize = args[5];
  String distributionType = args[6];

  if (args.length < 0) {
   System.err.println("No arguements are passed");
  } ```

Comment: ```CoreGraph cGraph = UtilsManagement.readEdgeTxtFileReturnGraph(edgeDataSetFile);
YenGraph yGraph = new YenGraph(edgeDataSetFile);
ArrayList<Node> nodesList = UtilsManagement.readTxtNodeFile(nodeDatasetFile);
cGraph.setNodesWithInfo(nodesList);
int distributionValue = Integer.parseInt(distributionType);
int querySize = Integer.parseInt(queryObjectSize);
int dataSize = Integer.parseInt(dataObjectSize);
switch (distributionValue) {
case 1: RandomObjectGenerator.generateUniformRandomObjectsOnMap()
case 2: RandomObjectGenerator.zgenerateCUUCDistribution()```

Comment: I am passing the text files along with the arguments. With the ```--files``` option I get IllegalArgumentException error!

Comment: As you said I have added the datasets on each executor and the same file path. The code seems to be executing. I can see the progress and actually see the result as well.

Comment: I don't know what `UtilsManagement` class does, but I assume it can only read local filesystem. Also, your if condition should go before you actually index the args array, and throw an error, not simply print. You should not manually copy files into YARN machines because Spark will pick those, at random, mostly. Edit your question to include your code and attempt with files argument rather than comment